# How can I render it all in cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

How can I get cycles render to show everything like Blender render, I mean transparencies, diffuse, UV textures?

Is there a quick way to see it all like a preset template? 
If not, is there a simple versatile setup where all can be rendered is applied?

[UPDATE]
I don't understand what the confusion is all about, when I render in Blender cycles I don't see transparencies, diffuse, UV textures. Then they say you have to use nodes but I want to skip using nodes, if I never use a node ever again it will be too soon. I'm asking for a shortcut, a py script, a 3rd party plugin, anything to just generate all the nodes automatically, instantly.

Comment: What do you mean "*show everything like Blender render*" ? Could you clarify?

Comment: "I mean transparencies, diffuse, UV textures"

Comment: Do you mean Render Layer Passes?

Comment: When you mean *"show everything"*, do you mean on the viewport? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean. Or do you mean a material that has a bunch of attributes already built in? Maybe the "so called" ubershaders". I'm unclear on what you are asking, but maybe the new Principled BSDF shader available starting v. 2.7.9 is what you are after?

Comment: You want to render in cycles but skip nodes? That's gonna be tough, material creation is an essential part of it. It's like trying to open a restaurant and not wanting to learn how to cook

Comment: But I already created all the materials, UV maps, assigned all the transparencies and specular values so why does cycles need me to do it again? That is what is frustrating for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use nodes (Node editor)

for example, to use uv texture with cycles, you add the texture to a material via uv mapping editor, then in the node editor you tick the box that says "use nodes" and go to add>texture>image

[image]

Comment: Is there an all ready made node presets that I can download or install? It's like I love to cook from scratch but don't ask me to harvest the crops too. There should be a way to take all the setting from Blender render and auto node the whole thing with just a click... right?

Comment: Uhm. Its kind of a personal thing for what you need. You add nodes that you want and thats it.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?247271-Cycles-Automatic-Material-Textures-Node

Comment: There might be something current out there for my needs.

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Blender_Cycles_Materials_Converter

Answer (score -2):

If you want to render without using nodes you can use a 3rd party renderer such as Thea, which doesn't use nodes for rendering. Plus it is open source and is a free plugin for Blender as far as I can tell.

Found here:

https://www.thearender.com/site/index.php/products/thea-for-blender

[EDIT]

This doesn't work for me, been trying to get it to work to no avail. But I changed my mind about nodes once I found out about EEVEE. A new real time engine for Blender will help greatly as I'll get instant results as I play around without having to wait for renders.